# My android app crashes while I'm trying to change activities

Tags: android, android-studio, crash

I'm trying to develop a game in android studio, but when I change activities the game crashes.
The logcat says: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference.
It also says that I have a problem with the Display.java file at the line 51.

display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Display">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menuButton"
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="MENU"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_countdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="60sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start_pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="start"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_countdown"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:onClick="tryagain"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_start_pause"
        android:text="reset"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="356dp"
        android:text="SETTINGS"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <!-- tools:visibility="visible"-->

    <!-- tools:visibility="visible"-->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="81dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="81dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
        android:text="PLAY"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leaderButton"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="288dp"
        android:text="LEADERBOARD"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />



    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottieAnimationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="246dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-1dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="tryagain.json"
        app:lottie_loop="true" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottieAnimationViewWin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="246dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-3dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="win.json"
        app:lottie_loop="true" />

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottieAnimationViewTimesUp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="246dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_fileName="timesup.json"
        app:lottie_loop="true" />
    <!-- tools:visibility="visible"-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Display.java

```
    package com.example.testpaz;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Display extends Activity {
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 10000;
    private static final long NEGATIVE_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 5000;
    private long NegativeTimeInMillis = NEGATIVE_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private Button mButtonStartPause;
    private Button mButtonReset;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private LottieAnimationView tryAgainAnim;
    private LottieAnimationView winAnim;
    private LottieAnimationView timesUpAnim;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    private ImageView bg;
    private Button playB;
    private Button settB;
    private Button leaderB;
    private Button menuB;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bg = findViewById(R.id.bg);
        tryAgainAnim = findViewById(R.id.lottieAnimationView);
        winAnim = findViewById(R.id.lottieAnimationViewWin);
        timesUpAnim = findViewById(R.id.lottieAnimationViewTimesUp);
        mTextViewCountDown = findViewById(R.id.text_view_countdown);
        mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
        mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        playB = findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        settB = findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
        leaderB = findViewById(R.id.leaderButton);
        menuB = findViewById(R.id.menuButton);
        menuB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                backToMenu();
            }
        });
        playB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startGame();
            }
        });
        mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTimerRunning) {
                    pauseTimer();
                } else {
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        });
        mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetTimer();
            }
        });

        updateCountDownText();
    }
    private void backToMenu(){
        menuB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        playB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        settB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        leaderB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mTextViewCountDown.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        timesUpAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tryAgainAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    private void startGame(){
        menuB.bringToFront();
        menuB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        settB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        leaderB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mTextViewCountDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void startTimer() {
        final MediaPlayer alarmSound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alarm_sound);
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 10) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
                updateCountDownText();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                bg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
                alarmSound.start();
                timesUpAnim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTimerRunning = false;
                mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
                mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }.start();
        mTimerRunning = true;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Stop");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tryAgainAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    private void pauseTimer() {
        final MediaPlayer victSound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.vicory_sound);
        final MediaPlayer failSound = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.fail_sound);
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
        mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis >= 4990 && mTimeLeftInMillis <= 5010){
            winAnim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            victSound.start();
        }else{
            tryAgainAnim.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            failSound.start();
        }
    }
    private void resetTimer() {
        mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
        updateCountDownText();
        timesUpAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tryAgainAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        winAnim.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    private void updateCountDownText() {
        //int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
        String timeLeftFormatted;
        int seconds = Math.abs((int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis - NegativeTimeInMillis) / 1000) % 60);
        int centiSec = Math.abs((int) ((mTimeLeftInMillis - NegativeTimeInMillis) / 10) % 100);
        if (mTimeLeftInMillis <= 7000 && mTimeLeftInMillis >= 5000){
            bg.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0, 0, 0));
        }

        if(mTimeLeftInMillis >= 5000){
            timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", seconds, centiSec);

        }else{
            timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "-%02d:%02d", seconds, centiSec);
        }

        mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
-03-29 12:14:36.008 10868-10868/com.example.testpaz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testpaz, PID: 10868
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testpaz/com.example.testpaz.Display}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testpaz.Display.onCreate(Display.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: on a null object reference means you forget to connect xml button to class. Check again the ids of buttons.

Comment: can you post the xml file

Comment: Try to add onClick to xml then call that function in proper activity. Here we don't even know what button causes problem. Upload only needed stuff not all files.

Answer (score 0):

Your Display activity is inflating `activity_main.xml`, not `display.xml`.

Replace

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout.display);
```

Comment: Same stacktrace or something different?

Comment: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at com.example.testpaz.Display.onCreate(Display.java:39) its the setContentView line

Comment: That's a problem with the layout itself since it seems to be pointing at that  `setContentView()` line.